# Is it possible to extend a class that already inherits from another class?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, easeljs

I know the direct answer is no here but I've spoken with a couple people who seem to think it's possible. Here is my code:

```
var Tile = function(xPos, yPos, state) {
    this.createTile(xPos, yPos, state);
}

Tile.prototype = new createjs.Shape();

Tile.prototype.createTile = function(xPos, yPos, state) {
    // debugger;
    this.x = xPos;
    this.y = yPos;
    this.onState = state;

    var fillCommand = this.graphics.beginFill("#969696").command;
    var shapeCommand = this.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, 50, 50, 10).command;

    this.on("click", function(){this.toggleState(fillCommand);});

    stage.addChild(this);
    stage.update();
}

Tile.prototype.toggleState = function(fillCommand) {
    if (this.onState === true) {
        fillCommand.style = "#969696";
        stage.update();
        this.onState = false;
        } else if (this.onState === false) {
        fillCommand.style = "#000000";
        stage.update();
        this.onState = true;
    }
}
```

Shape() is implemented in easeljs if anyone is familiar with it. Basically here I'm creating a Tile class to represent little rounded squares that will change color when they're pressed. Syntax-wise I get no errors nothing displays on the web page. I already have the correct code to call Tile and the canvas already set up or I'd put that code here too. What I'm asking here is, do I have the right idea in this implementation?

Comment: Why is the direct answer "no"? This looks like average everyday JavaScript inheritance. Only change may be to invoke the `Shape` constructor inside the `Tile` constructor, like `createjs.Shape.call(this)`. Also, `Tile.prototype = Object.create(createjs.Shape.prototype)` is generally preferred.

Comment: I know that javascript only supports single inheritance, which is why I said the direct answer is no. Is this wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Its a little unconventional but if it works for you then more power to you. The more common way  to inherit from Shape would be doing something like

```
Tile.prototype = Object.create(createjs.Shape.prototype);
Tile.prototype.constructor = Tile;
```

Inheritance in Javascript is a little strange so, unless you have the time and energy to go down a deep rabbit hole, I would recommend just sticking with what's working. If you do feel like reading more this is a great article to get you started: http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

Comment: +1 this is the cleanest way to set up prototypical inheritance in _JavaScript_, you may also want to have something like `createjs.Shape.call(this, foo, bar, baz, etc);` somewhere in _function_ `Tile` depending on your needs.

Comment: Well my problem is that it doesn't give me any errors outright, but it's not displaying. So I'm thinking I"m actually doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

EaselJS contributor here - you can absolutely extend EaselJS classes. There is actually a [tutorial on the EaselJS site](http://www.createjs.com/tutorials/Inheritance/) for it. As other people have mentioned, JavaScript inheritance is kind of a pain, and not necessarily the best approach (for example, I always compose shapes/sprites instead of inheriting from them. But it is totally possible, just look at the EaselJS hierarchy: `EventDispatcher > DisplayObject > Bitmap`.

With your example, you should probably use the approach in the tutorial, where you override initialize, and ensure the superclasses version is called. Its a little dirty, but used extensively until EaselJS 0.7.1 (the latest release).

**The New Way**

Even better though, the latest version of CreateJS (only available in GitHub as the NEXT version, which should be tagged and published to the CDN soon!) has a brand new model for inheritance that is even easier, and does things like automatically injecting super methods, including the ability to call the super constructor.

```
function MyClass(arg) {
    this.EventDispatcher_constructor();
    this.doSomethingWith(arg);
}
var p = createjs.extend(MyClass, createjs.EventDispatcher);

// Add new methods
p.doSomethingWith = function() {
    // whatever
}

// Override methods
p.addEventListener = function(name, listener) {
    this.EventDispatcher_addEventListener(name, listener);
    // custom stuff here
}

// Promote super class methods to MyClass
window.MyClass = createjs.promote(MyClass, "EventDispatcher");
```

This is way cleaner, easier to use, and in our tests works great!

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Here is the announcement on the new class model in CreateJS: http://blog.createjs.com/new-createjs-class-model/

Comment: Updating my code I get an error on the line

`var fillCommand = this.graphics.beginFill("#969696").command;`

It's telling me can not read property 'beginFill' of undefined.


The entire reason why I'm doing it as a class implementation is because eventually I am going to track other tiles that are being created in order to turn their states on or off. These Tiles are essentially prefabs that are getting generated. Would an easier implementation not use the class model that I'm trying to do?